# Can't send html email with laravel + mandrill

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, mandrill

I am using Laravel 4.2 and mandrill plugin. This way I can send emails using the laravel syntax (swiftmailer) and the mails are sent by mandrill. However, I can't seem to send HTML messages. They appear as text emails with htmltags inside. What could be wrong?

```
    //Send email    
    $emailName = $_POST['emailName'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
    $emailSubject = $_POST['emailSubject'];
    $emailMessage = html_entity_decode($_POST['emailMessage']);
    $emailFrom = $_POST['emailFrom'];
    $emailFromName = $_POST['emailFromName'];
    $pathToAttachement = $_POST['pathToAttachement'];

    $data = array('emailAddress' => $emailAddress, 'emailName' => $emailName, 'emailSubject' => $emailSubject, 'emailFrom' => $emailFrom, 'emailFromName' => $emailFromName, 'pathToAttachement' => $pathToAttachement);
    Mail::send('admin.emails.blank', array('msg' => $emailMessage), function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->setContentType('text/html');
        $message->from($data['emailFrom'], $data['emailFromName']);
        $message->to($data['emailAddress'], $data['emailName'])->subject($data['emailSubject']);
        $message->attach($data['pathToAttachement']);

    });
```

Comment: Can you show what's in the `/admin/emails/blank.blade.php`?

Comment: I only output the message:
    {{{ $msg }}}

Comment: I just realized that I am escaping the content myself by using three accolades...thanks to you peterm. So I changed it to {{ $msg }} and now works fine. Stupid mistake.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked you this question

Comment: Why are you using `$_POST` instead of `Input::get()`? Why are you doing `setContentType('text/html')` when Laravel's `Mail::send` has a parameter for the HTML content of the email (it's HTML by default, and you can do `Mail::send(array('html.view', 'text.view'), $data, $callback);` if you want)?

Comment: all true, however I was tweaking everything to find out what was wrong. And this in fact should work. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `blank.blade.php` template make sure you use double curly braces so that you don't escape the content

```
{{ $msg }}
```